# How to automate efficiently testing Reactive webflux API steaming endpoints?

Tags: asynchronous, automation, karate, reactive

I was hoping to get some help/hint for test-automating **Reactive Webflux API** with any available open source tools in the market.

As reactive programming promotes an asynchronous, non-blocking, event-driven approach to data processing, we at work decided to go with it. But there comes the question about automating the testing.

- What are the industry standards to test and automate the asynchronous streaming services?
- What if stream ends in an infinite loop waiting for some unsuccessful data? Will there be a timeout mechanism in testing possible?
- Is **Karate DSL** a good candidate to automate **asynchronous** Reactive WebFlux APIs?
- *If not*, is there any other way to automate it?

Any little help/hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if something is good or bad can lead to opinionated answers, the question should be rephrased to include more specifics. You can either argue that something is better or worse in your question, or you can write something in said technology and then ask a more specific question as to why you think something is bad or not.

Comment: please read the linked answer. in short if you can code it in java, you can test it using karate. and yes async is possible: https://github.com/intuit/karate#async

Comment: @Toerktumlare, my ask is to test and automate the streaming webflux service responses. The link you provided does not make any sense.

Comment: The link and the closing of the question was done before you edited the question. Then you need to explain why the link provided does not answer the question. I voted to close due to risk of opinionated answers.

Comment: also, you are asking a lot of large and broad questions. You should narrow down and ask one single question. Question is way too broad.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, though I explained little broader, the question is all about finding good solution for test automation for webFlux streaming services.  How in the world you can express in one line?   Coming to the link you provided, it is about reading .avro file and converting as Json file. How could it relates to my question?

Comment: @PeterThomas, sorry for the confusion. I was good with your solution. I was pointing about the link provided by Toerktumlare in the question saying my question is duplicate

Comment: @Maaza ah. deleted my comment, you're all good 